# Get the href of each element inside a div and use it

Tags: html, jquery, onclick

I have the following code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(".tmb:first-child").attr("onclick", "location.href='location-one.html'");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>First element</p>
  <a href="location-one.html">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>Second element</p>
  <a href="location-two.html">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>Third element</p>
  <a href="location-three.html">Click me</a>
</div>
```

This works if I repeat it for every `.tmb-div` and change the nth-child number and the url. But eventually there will dynamically created more `.tmb-div`'s in the future. So is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this would help.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tmb").each(function() {
    let url = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      window.location.href = url;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>First element</p>
  <a href="location-one.html">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>Second element</p>
  <a href="location-two.html">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class="tmb">
  <p>Third element</p>
  <a href="location-three.html">Click me</a>
</div>
```